# I have a html or javascript problem with m website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project of my own and implemented some code for the navbar and search bar but it won't work as supposed to work IDK why my guess is javascript code is not working or something else but i can't find the solution to it so if anybody could help it would be amazing

Here is a link to my code on code pen:
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/webdeveloper-gif/pen/abpgXyQ)

```
<a href="https://codepen.io/webdeveloper-gif/pen/abpgXyQ">click here</a>
```

Comment: this link don't border with it because it wouldn't let me post the question without it IDK why

Comment: Please specify details about the expected behaviour and how the actual behaviour differs from it.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Thanks man i figure it out already but I tried your solution just out of curiosity and it worked, sorry about low detail i am new to StackOverflow :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using Jquery but you never include it.
The error is : **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**
you can add inside your `<head> </head>` the cdn of [Jquery](https://code.jquery.com/) line:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

```css
html,body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
body{
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
}
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url(https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/481052.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
.content {
    width: 94%;
    margin: 4em auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.logo {
    line-height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 46px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;
}

nav ul {
    line-height: 60px;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 40px;
    transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
    background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-icon {
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 786px) {

    .logo {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        margin-top: 16px;
    }

    nav ul {
        max-height: 0px;
        background: #000;
    }

    nav.black ul {
        background: #000;
    }

    .showing {
        max-height: 34em;
    }

    nav ul li {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 24px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .menu-icon {
        display: block;
    }

}
/* Css for animated search box */
::selection {
    background: #212129;
}

.search-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
}
.search-wrapper.active {}

.search-wrapper .input-holder {    
    height: 70px;
    width:70px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
    border-radius:6px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder {
    width:450px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-input {
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    padding:0px 70px 0 20px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background: transparent;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border:none;
    outline:none;
    font-family:"Open Sans", Arial, Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    color:#FFF;
    transform: translate(0, 60px);
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-input {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 10px); 
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon {
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    border:none;
    border-radius:6px;
    background: #FFF;
    padding:0px;
    outline:none;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    float:right;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon {
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span {
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position:relative;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all .4s cubic-bezier(0.650, -0.600, 0.240, 1.650);
}
.search-wrapper.active .input-holder .search-icon span {
    transform: rotate(-45deg); 
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before, .search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
    position: absolute; 
    content:'';
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::before {
    width: 4px;
    height: 11px;
    left: 9px;
    top: 18px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background: #FE5F55;
}
.search-wrapper .input-holder .search-icon span::after {
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    border-radius: 16px;
    border: 4px solid #FE5F55;
}
.search-wrapper .close {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top:24px;
    right:20px;
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotate(-180deg);
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.285, -0.450, 0.935, 0.110);
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
.search-wrapper.active .close {
    right:-50px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: all .6s cubic-bezier(0.000, 0.105, 0.035, 1.570);
    transition-delay: 0.5s;
}
.search-wrapper .close::before, .search-wrapper .close::after {
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    background: #FE5F55;
    border-radius: 2px;
}
.search-wrapper .close::before {
    width: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    left: 10px;
    top: 0px;
}
.search-wrapper .close::after {
    width: 25px;
    height: 5px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div class="menu-icons">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="logo">
                    LOGO
                </div>
                <div class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Favorites</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                  console.log("g");
                $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
                $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
                });
                });

                // Scrolling Effect

                $(window).on("scroll", function() {
                if($(window).scrollTop()) {
                $('nav').addClass('black');
                }

                else {
                $('nav').removeClass('black');
                }
                })
            </script>
            
            <div class="search-wrapper">
                <div class="input-holder">
                    <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="Type to search" />
                    <button class="search-icon" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"><span></span></button>
                </div>
                <span class="close" onclick="searchToggle(this, event);"></span>
            </div>

            <!--Javascript for search bar-->
            <script>
               function searchToggle(obj, evt){
                var container = $(obj).closest('.search-wrapper');
                if(!container.hasClass('active')){
                container.addClass('active');
                evt.preventDefault();
                }
                else if(container.hasClass('active') && $(obj).closest('.input-holder').length == 0){
                container.removeClass('active');
                // clear input
                container.find('.search-input').val('');
                }
                }
            </script>
        </header>
      
    </body>
    </html>
    
 

    <h1>hello world </h1>
    <h1> hello world</h1>
    <h1> hello world </h1>
    <h1> hello world </h1>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
    <h1> hello world</h1>
    <h1>hello world </h1>
    <h1> hello world</h1>
    <h1> hello world </h1>
    <h1> hello world </h1>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
    <h1>hello world</h1>
    <h1> hello world</h1>
    
    
</body>
</html>
```

and then all of the javascript changes will be made.